# Ошибка : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in D:\server\OSPanel\domains\job\test\pop.php on line 619

Tags: php

Не замечаю проблему,может кто-то заметит :

```
if($t==1){
            echo "<table width='100%' border='0' bordercolor='white'>";
                echo"<tr>"; 
                echo"<td id='logo'>";           
                echo $logo; 
                echo"</td>";
                echo"<td rowspan='2' id='foto'>";
                    echo "<div class='bgc-img'>";
                    echo "<img src='$foto[$n]' 
                    width='50%' border='5' bordercolor='white' align='right'>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo $text[$n];
            echo"</td>";
            echo"</tr>";

        echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td id='menu' valign='top'>";
                for($i=1;$i<=count($name);$i++){
                    echo"<a href='?n=$id[$i]&m=$m&t=$t'>".$name[$i]."</a>";
            }
            else
            {
            echo "<table width='100%' border='0' bordercolor='white'>";
            echo"<tr id='logo'>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $logo;
            echo "</td>";
            echo"</tr>";
            echo"<td rowspan='2' id='foto'>";
            echo "<center>";
            echo "<div class='bgc-img'>";
            echo "<div class='content'>";
                    echo "<img src='$foto[$n]' 
                    width='50%' border='5' bordercolor='white'><br>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
                    echo $text[$n];
                    echo "</center>";
            echo"</td>";
                }
                echo"<a href='?n=$n&m=1&t=$t'><img src='img/ua.jpg'width='100px' height='50px'></a><p>";
                echo"<a href='?n=$n&m=2&t=$t'><img src='img/ru.png' width='100px' height='50px'></a><p>";
```

Comment: Здесь начало ошибки `for($i=1;$i<=count($name);$i++){ `. Может хватит на SO выкладывать ошибки синтаксиса, а стоит скачать и работать в нормальной IDE, которая этот синтаксис подсвечивает?

Comment: возможно,но вопросы новичков об ошибках синтаксиса никогда не закончаться

Answer (score 0):

```
   for($i=1;$i<=count($name);$i++){
                    echo"<a href='?n=$id[$i]&m=$m&t=$t'>".$name[$i]."</a>";
            }
            else
            {
```

здесь }  только для foreach  а для  if нету так  а  по твоему как будет работать твой код если когда условия ешо не закончилось пишется else  я тоже еслиб был место кода вобще не сработал:)надо писать так

```
 for($i=1;$i<=count($name);$i++){
                        echo"<a href='?n=$id[$i]&m=$m&t=$t'>".$name[$i]."</a>";
                }}
                else
                {
```